# Redirecting a page after form submission

Tags: 7, forms

If I have a module that is creating a page, after form submission for that page, how would I redirect? Is there a function to do this in Drupal? I imagine that I would put the redirect command inside my function that executes after form submission, correct?

Comment: Have you read [Form API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7), especially [Working with #redirect](https://api.drupal.org/comment/18139#comment-18139) post?

Comment: Which is better, the drupal_goto() or the redirect property?

Comment: Property is there specifically to work with forms. It's less universal than goto, but also practically immune to conflict with other form mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the `drupal_goto()` function there's also the `'redirect'` property in the `$form_state`

See https://api.drupal.org/comment/18139#comment-18139